# OpenGL 3.3 Ubuntu (Virtual Machine)

Tags: macos, opengl, virtual-machine

I need openGL 3.3 or higher to use GLSL 3.3. My problem is that I have Mac Os X which doesn't allow to use a version higher than 2.1 of OpenGL. I've installed a virtual machine of Ubuntu inside my system but also has the version 2.1 of OpenGL. I don't understand what's going on because I have an AMD Radeon HD 6490M 256 MB which is compatible with version 4.1 of OpenGL. Is there any way that I can use openGL 3.3 or higher without doing a disk partition?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I don't understand what's going on because I have an AMD Radeon HD 6490M 256 MB which is compatible with version 4.1 of OpenGL

The GPU serves the host machine. The virtual machine sees only some dumb framebuffer device, or the OpenGL API available to the VM running on the host passed through the guest.

If you want to leverage the OpenGL-4 capabilities you must install an OS that can access the GPU natively. Also, if you want to run Linux you'll have to install the proprietary *fglrx* drivers (also called Catalyst for Linux), as the open source drivers that ship as distribution default haven't caught up yet.

Answer (score 0):

> Is there any way that I can use openGL 3.3 or higher **without doing a disk partition**?

Upgrade to [OS X 10.9](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OS_X_Mavericks#Features) when it comes out or grab the beta.

Or find some VM software for OS X that supports VGA passthrough.

If you're willing to repartition you can install Windows or Linux natively and use the drivers from AMD.

Comment: I'd rather not to install Windows or Linux natively. About OS X 10.9 I'm waiting to get it but the point it's I need now because I've already started the course. So, I'll search in the web about that kind of VM. Thanks you so much.