# Upgrade a ubuntu virtual machine to OpenGl 4

Tags: linux, ubuntu, opengl, virtual-machine, virtualbox

I need OpenGL 4 for a classes of visual computing and i have Mac Os X which doesn't allow to use a version higher than 2.1. I've installed a virtual machine with ubuntu but i can't upgrade it higher than openGL 3.3 .

Consulting this topic [OpenGL 3.3 Ubuntu (Virtual Machine)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18771347/opengl-3-3-ubuntu-virtual-machine)
I understand that i had to install the fglrx drivers on my virtual machine but i don't know how i can get through. 
I've tried to "sudo apt-get install fglrx" but it failed.
I don't know what to tried i'm a kind of noob in visual computing.

edit: my mac is compatible with OpenGL 4.1

Comment: Before anything else be sure your Mac has a graphics card that allows OpenGL 4. In [this](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT202823) link you can see the cards.

Comment: sorry i forgot to precise , yes it is it's a macbook bro from mid 2014 so it's compatible to OpenGL 4.1

Comment: Go to "system configuration", "sofware and updates" "aditional drivers". (Names may vary, my locale is not English)

Comment: on the virtual machine or on the macos ? @Ripi2

Comment: The VM, of course. You want drivers for Ubuntu, not OSX.

Comment: I'm on it , how can i install fglrx then ?

Comment: fglrx is the **propietary** driver from AMD for Radeon cards (They call it "Catalyst"). Perhaps the free, open source, dirver that ships with Ubuntu may allow OGL 4. Select one or the other.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/153682/discussion-between-valentin-mercier-and-ripi2).

Comment: MacOS X does allow OpenGL >=2.1. YOu just have to use a _core_ _profile_, which you should use anyway.

Comment: yes i know that but i can't upgrade the core profile of my virtual ubuntu machine up to 3.3 and it failed to create an environnement when i try to create an opengl4 environment

Answer (score 3):

> and i have Mac Os X which doesn't allow to use a version higher than 2.1

If you have a reasonably new MacOS then it should support OpenGL-4, **iff** your GPU is OpenGL-4 capable as well (https://developer.apple.com/opengl/OpenGL-Capabilities-Tables.pdf p. 34ff). However MacOS-X does support only **core** profile OpenGL versions, so if you try to create a *compatibility* profile that will fail and fall back to 2.1.

If your GPU does't OpenGL-4.x in MacOS-X then it's unlikely that you can get OpenGL-4.x support in a VM with the GPU passed through. But with Linux you can use a recent version of Mesa with it's software rasterizer, which is OpenGL-4.x capable.

Comment: *However MacOS-X does support only core profile OpenGL versions*. Huh. I seem to remember having been able to create compat 3.3 contexts a while ago.

Comment: @BartekBanachewicz: Could that have been with NVidia's proprietary driver installed? AFAIK the default Apple drivers don't support compatibility profiles.

Comment: Apple Compatibility Profile can be created by setting  `NSOpenGLPFAOpenGLProfile` and `NSOpenGLProfileVersionLegacy` in the pixel format attributtes.

Comment: What Apple does not provide is Forward Compatible profile.

Comment: Seeing a lot of red in the Software columns for GL 4.0 on [Mesamatrix](https://mesamatrix.net/), did they add 4.0 support really recently?

Comment: @datenwolf If anything, that would be the Intel driver for me.